# Override bundle template from another bundle in Symfony 4/5

Tags: php, symfony, templates, bundle

because bundle inheritance is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and will be removed in 4.0, I'm finding a new solution. I have:

- Application
- FooBundle
- BarBundle

And I haven't problem with overriding templates in Application. But I need to override templates from BarBundle in FooBundle. It was so easy with bundle inheritance but I'm lost now :)

I tried twig namespaces - no success, but I configured it in wrong way maybe. My goal is to have base templates in BarBundle that I can override in FooBundle or Application or both. (it is because BarBundle is third-party bundle and FooBundle is my bundle used in many projects).

Is it still possible without bundle inheritance and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html I have not done this myself for awhile but it seems easy enough.  Another approach is to add [namespaced twig paths](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html) .

Comment: @Cerad: To me, that stuff looks like configuration for your own application, but I think the OP is looking for a solution encapsulated in his bundle

Comment: @NicoHaase The second link shows you how FooBundle can add a twig namespace to basically override BarBundle templates.  And then you can add one in the application to override what FooBundle has.  I used to do this sort of nonsense before giving up on twig.

Answer (score 9):

I will show how it looks in my case(Symfony 5.1). To overwrite views for bundles `JMoseCommandSchedulerBudnle` and `TwigBundle`:

**1. Create your own directory with custom third party bundle templates(I put them In `Resources/views/bundles`):**

[image]

**2. Create folders for each bundle where you want to override templates:**

[image]

**3. Create custom templates(for example to create custom Twig Error Pages):**

[image]

**4. Implement `PrependExtensionInterface` and add custom paths to the Twig Extension configuration:**

```php
class AppngCmsExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface {
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // I recommend using FileLocator here 
        $thirdPartyBundlesViewFileLocator = (new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/views/bundles'));

        $container->loadFromExtension('twig', [
            'paths' => [
                $thirdPartyBundlesViewFileLocator->locate('JMoseCommandSchedulerBundle') => 'JMoseCommandScheduler',
                $thirdPartyBundlesViewFileLocator->locate('TwigBundle') => 'Twig',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

So I have recently needed same functionality and with help from comment @NicoHasse I managed to make working example

In your bundle bundle extension class you need to implement `PrependExtensionInterface` and then you can modify twig paths. Then you need to know original namespace your you need to override (`php bin/console debug:twig`).

You can confirm its working with twig debug command where you should see your path at first place of that namespace.

```
class YourExtensionClass extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->loadFromExtension('twig', [
            'paths' => [
                '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/xx/yy/zzz' => 'OriginalVNamespace',
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more comprehensible example

Let's start with making some assumptions

**Your bundle's name:** AcmeBundle

**Bundle you want to override:** FOSUserBundle

Run command `php bin/console debug:twig` and find the namespace of the bundle you want to override. In this case it's `@FOSUser`.

Your bundle extension should look like this

```
<?php // src/AcmeBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeExtension.php

namespace AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

// ...

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;

class AcmeExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    // ...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->loadFromExtension('twig', array(
            'paths' => array(
                '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AcmeBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views' => 'FOSUser', // You use the namespace you found earlier here. Discard the `@` symbol.
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Now you can create `src/AcmeBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig` to override the login template of FOSUserBundle.

This was just an example for FOSUserBundle. You can change bundle names depending on what you're trying to override.