# Override bundle template from another bundle

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm developing a plugin for Sylius e-commerce framework.
I'm using Symfony 4 with Sylius standard 1.2.
In this plugin (which is just a Symfony Bundle), I would like to override a template defined in SyliusAdminBundle and I would like to avoid to copy it in AppBundle views folder.

I tried to follow explanations showed here : [Override bundle template from another bundle in symfony 3.4/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605939/override-bundle-template-from-another-bundle-in-symfony-3-4-4)

but I can't figure out how to make it work !

Do you have any idea on how I could process ?

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2783 - same issue, they also have a fix for that in there.

Comment: @DominicWehrmann, no it's not the same question. I want to override the template in a third party bundle, not in the AppBundle project

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. How about forking that other project and make the changes then?

Comment: I would like to avoid forking Sylius project. Anyway, if it's not possible, I will use an other approach. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Hmm, I thought about it again. You could try to put your 'new' template into your third-party bundle's Resource folder, as specified in my first link, does that work?

Comment: @DominicWehrmann, no, it does not work, even if use twig namespacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to either put the overriden template in `templates/bundles/SyliusAdminBundle/path/to/template.html.twig`. The same can be done from inside a theme: `app/themes/ThemeName/SyliusAdminBundle/path/to/template.html.twig`. Often plugins simply give instructions to put the adjustments in your project. It's not the most flexible, but it's very clear to the project what templates have been changed.

For more background: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/customization/template.html.

Symfony used to have a 'bundle inheritance' mechanism to do how you initially planned on doing this, but that feature has been deprecated from version 3.4: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-deprecated-bundle-inheritance.

Comment: "Often plugins simply give instructions to put the adjustments in your project. It's not the most flexible, but it's very clear to the project what templates have been changed." Indeed I often saw plugin giving instructions like this but I wanted to avoid this.